# MVC Forms Authentication prevent reset of sliding window timer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hi I'm using the default ASP.NET MVC Forms Authentication Membership Provider.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="" timeout="300" slidingExpiration="true"/>
</authentication>
```

I have a polling method that polls every minute. Whenever this method polls the expiration timer gets reset and the authentication cookie is valid for another 300 seconds.

I was wondering if it is possible to define per function if this the expiration timer gets reset or not, because this polling function should not reset this timer and the user gets logged off automatically after 300 seconds.

I'm using MVC 3.0.0.1

**Edit**

Regarfing to Adam Carr's answer. You're right, that would be pretty simple.
But I'm not able to put the logic in the Javascript part. We have a policy that allows only one session per user. If a user with the same credentials logges in with the same credentials in another browser the first users sessions gets terminated and redirected to the login page.
It would be easy if we were able to use web sockets like SignalR, but in this case I think it would be too much overhead fur only one function.

Answer (score 1):

Why not put the logic in to the JavaScript sending the request. If you dont wont to reset the timer then don't send the keep alive.